# Hebrew text for Rambam's letter to Ovadia the Ger online and good Hebrew shiur on it

Tags: hebrew, sources-mekorot, conversion-to-judaism, rambam, adult-learning

Does anyone know where I can find the Hebrew text for the Rambam's letter to Ovadia the Ger online, and a good Hebrew language shiur on it?

Comment: rambamsources, welcome to Mi Yodeya and thank you for bringing your question here.  Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Answer (score 3):

The Rambam wrote three letters to Ovadya the Ger. The Hebrew text can be found in Teshuvos HaRambam [42](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1733&pgnum=107), [345](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1733&pgnum=376) and (probably the most famous one) [369](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1733&pgnum=402). These are the only letters to him in the volume (according to the index).

[Here](https://meirtv.com/shiurim-series/21002/) is a Hebrew lecture series on them that I found in a search but didn't watch.